# How to automatically load a function

Tags: r

I have created some functions in R and whenever I need any of those functions, I need to re-create that. Please suggest me the way and steps so that i can use directly those functions in any session of R without recreating them.

Comment: do you use source()? source() loads the function provided the path is correct

Comment: and what do you mean by recreating them everytime?

Comment: http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html

Comment: #joel.wilson :  I need that fuction is available everytime i login into R session currently when i login and i want to use that particular function i need to execute again the script of that function definition and then i can able to use that. I need a way to include that function in R session so that i need not to create it everytime.

Answer (score 3):

While Carl's answer is acceptable, I personally think that this is exactly the situation where you should package your functions and simply call them as a library.

There are very good reasons to do this:

- Documentation (with emphasis!)
- Tests
- Easy loading (`library(mypackage)`)
- Easy to share and portable across systems
- Easy to use within reporting (Rmd/knitr)
- Reduces potential for duplication
- Learning the R package system will be a strong part of your toolbox and other benefits of organizing your code appropriately will become apparent.

Comment: I support this message strongly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a series of functions that I need across all sessions. The trick is to add them to your .First file so that they are sourced into every session globally.

A helper function to find your first-file

```
find.first <- function(edit = FALSE, show_lib = TRUE){

  candidates <- c(Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE"),
                  file.path(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "etc", "Rprofile.site"),
                  Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE_USER"),
                  file.path(getwd(), ".Rprofile")
                  )

  first_hit <- Filter(file.exists, candidates)

  if(show_lib & !edit){
    return(first_hit)
  }else {
    file.edit(first_hit)
  }
}
```

Say your scripts you use everywhere are in '/mystuff/R'

```
# Pop open the first Rprofile file.
find.first(edit = TRUE)
```

You will see something like this:

```
##Emacs please make this -*- R -*-
## empty Rprofile.site for R on Debian
##
## Copyright (C) 2008 Dirk Eddelbuettel and GPL'ed
##
## see help(Startup) for documentation on ~/.Rprofile and Rprofile.site

# ## Example of .Rprofile
# options(width=65, digits=5)
# options(show.signif.stars=FALSE)
# setHook(packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"),
#         function(...) grDevices::ps.options(horizontal=FALSE))
# set.seed(1234)
#.First <- function(){}
#
#
```

Edit the function to something like:

```
.First <- function(){
  all_my_r <- list.files('/mystuff/R', full.names = T,
                         recursive = T, pattern = ".R$" )
    lapply(all_my_r, function(i){
     tryCatch(source(i), error = function(e)NULL)
    })

}
```

Save the file. Then restart the session.

Comment: Oh...and in case it wasn't obvious un-comment the #.First